# ¿Hay manera de acceder a las vistas del activity container desde el Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Con mi pregunta me refiero, por ejemplo, cuando el usuario haga click en un button que está en el layout del container envíe argumentos del FragmentA al FragmentB (*como por ejemplo, un texto insertado en un EditText dentro del layout del FragmentA*) .

La solución más rápida y sencilla fue mejor agregar el button al layout del FragmentA, pero por cuestiones de diseño me gustaría que el button estuviese en el container.
También intenté que el **bundle** se creara y se enviara para cuando se hace llamar los métodos onPause o incluso onDestroyView u onDestroy del FragmentA, ya que, cuando presiono el button del container, hago llamar el fragmentManager para **reemplazar** la vista del container por el FragmentB, pero no funcionó, se crasehaba...

Aquí abajo les anexo mi código. **El MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.cuarentena;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonNext = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);

        FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerFragment, fragmentA).commit();
        // La vista inicial del container es el FragmentA

        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerFragment, fragmentB).commit();
                // Luego reemplazo el container con la vista del FragmentB.
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**El FragmentA:**

```
package com.example.cuarentena;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private EditText inputText;

    public FragmentA() {
    }

    public static FragmentA newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        inputText = view.findViewById(R.id.input01);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), inputText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intenté que se enviara para cuando el fragment llame su método onPause, pero no me
        funcionaba. Lo curioso es que el Toast si me lo generaba, con el mensaje que escribía, pero
        a la hora de agregar el bundle, se crasehaba jajja. Lo mismo pasaba con el onDestroyView y
        con el onDestroy jajja.

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("NAME", inputText.getText().toString());
        FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
        fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);*/

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

**El FragmentB**

```
package com.example.cuarentena;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    private TextView textView;
    private String text;

    public FragmentB() {
    }

    public static FragmentB newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
//        assert getArguments() != null;
//        text = getArguments().getString("NAME");   Aquí es donde recibe el bundle del FragmentA
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textOutput);

//        textView.setText(text);   Aquí es donde lo muestro para corroborar que sí funcionó


    }
}
```

**La idea es esa, poder enviar argumentos registrados en el FragmentA al FragmentB tras presionar un Button que pertenezca al layout de container. ¿Es posible? ¿Cuáles serían las soluciones?**

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Un método en la activity que sea `public notificaB(infoParaElFragmentoB){}` y desde el fragmento A puedes usar `getActivity()`, le haces un casteo a `MainActivity` y desde ahí simplemente llamas al método `notificaB()` pasándole lo que quieras, y la activity puede encargarse de hacer lo que tenga que hacer con el otro fragmento

Comment: ¿Será que me puedas pasar una demostración en código? No soy muy bueno a la hora de implementarlo jaja... te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Si no eres muy bueno con la implementación y te lo dan casi hecho, qué aprendes? Venga venga, a picar código! Si no lo intentas, nunca aprenderás. En serio, ponle ganas, peléate un poco con el código, y si al final no te sale y tienes un error concreto, siempre podrás preguntar aquí! Pero preguntar es lo fácil, no siempre vas a poder preguntar! Y la única manera de mejorar es hacerlo, una y otra vez. Darte cabezazos hasta que al final sale y funciona!

Comment: Es que ya lo intenté :'v jajjaj pero tiene razón, le voy a invertir más tiempo. De cualquier modo, muchas gracias por su aportación. Me da satisfacción que si es posible hacer lo que tenía pensado. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de acceder es usando el contexto de la Activity que contiene el Fragment mediante `getActivity()`.

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.<id Vista>);
```

Comment: Muy amable señorita. Su respuesta al igual que los comentarios de Benito-B me fueron de gran ayuda. Les agradezco mucho su tiempo y conocimiento. No serán en vano.